# MVC asp.net - windows authentication redirect to specified action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, windows-authentication

Is this possible?

After I authenticate into my app, I want to check against the database if the logged user is imported or not. If not, it should be imported.

I want to do this right after the windows authentication has been successfully made.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What does "imported" mean?

Comment: Imported in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows credentials will be checked whenever a user attempts to execute an action that is decorated with the `[Authorize]` filter. You could simply derive a new filter from that one:

```
public class ImportAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
        {
             //If the base authorize returns true, then authorization has successfully
             //occurred. 
             var identity = httpContext.User.Identity;
             //You'll need to figure this part out
             ImportIdentityIfNotPresent(identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can restrict access by applying it at the action level:

```
[ImportAuthorizeAttribute]
public ActionResult Create()
```

Or at the controller level:

```
[ImportAuthorizeAttribute]
public class AdminController : Controller
```

Or even globally by editing `FilterConfig.cs` in `/App_Start':

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new Code.Filters.MVC.ImportAuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```

Comment: Is it ok to make this check at every query? My application should not allow any user to view a page as long as it isn't logged in with user credentials.

Comment: Yes, it is alright. Remember, HTTP is stateless, so if you are securing a page, authorization will happen with each request.